# jQuery reel & fancybox - works first time, but stops working if re-opened

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I post in the hope that someone has attempted to do the same thing as I have here, and run into the same problem and already found a fix or workaround.

I'm using jQuery [Reel](http://jquery.vostrel.cz/reel) and [Fancybox 2](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/) with the simple intention of putting a draggable reel inside a fancybox popup - the reel script is loaded by AJAX into the fancybox.

It works just fine the first time you use it in the page, but if you close the box and click to reopen it (without reloading the page) - you can't drag the image left and right (although mousewheel still works).

I'm guessing that an event handler is being cleared and not reattached, or something like that - but haven't used these two plugins together before.

I've set up a very basic page just containing these two components [here](http://www.codecraft.dyndns.org/fancy-reel/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another self answer - but in case someone finds it useful!

My question was related to Reel v1.1.4 which was the current version up until literally two days ago!

The brand new version (v1.2) fixes the issue and works with existing code without further modification.

Comment: I will when I can, I have to wait 2 days.  I'd delete the question but others might find it useful.